# The Gamma function and analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

I have that $\Gamma(z)$ is analytic when the real part of z,  Re$(z)$ $>0$, $z$ finite

and that $\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ is analytic for all (finite) $z$ except $z=0,-1,-2,...$

and that $\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ for Re$(z) > 0$, $z$ finite

Therefore by analytic continuation

$\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ for all (finite) $z$ except $z=0,-1,-2,...$

However my notes say that 
$\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ $\forall z$. How do I show this?

Comment: I think your notes are wrong, for specific values of z and are what you have above is correct for the analytic continuation $\Gamma$

Comment: what you can say is that on $\mathbb{C}$ : $z \Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$ where the equality is in the space of meromorphic functions (i.e. near a pole of order $m$, we consider $(z-z_0)^m \Gamma(z+1) = (z-z_0)^m z \Gamma(z)$)

Comment: and the analytic continuation of $\Gamma(z)$ is a particular case where you can consider vertical strips, but in general the analytic continuation is defined from a disk to an other disk, and hence on a path of such (non-empty intersection) disks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem the theorem is that for holomorphic functions "on the interior of two different paths" the analytic continuation doesn't depend on the chosen path. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation